# How to map strings across ObservableCollections

Tags: string, algorithm

I have two observable collections .
 Collection1 has a type, one of whose members is a string ( call it FileName)
 Collection2 has a type, one of whose members is a string ( call it ClientID)

The Filenames have in them the clientID as a substring . Thus a ClientID might be "12345" and the filename might be something like "OhLookFileFor12345goshdarnit.txt". I need to find a way to map these together . The first pass simple implementation looks like

```
 foreach (var V in Clients)
        {
            foreach (var Q in aofVM.OrganizerFiles)
            {
                if (Q.FileName.Contains(V.ClientID))
                {
                     // Match found
                }
            }
        }
```

Clearly this is somewhat less than awesome but is there any other standard way that is better/faster

Comment: Shall we guess the language? My money is on C#.

Comment: is there a way to extract the `ClientID` part out of `FileName`s? if yes, you could just sort both lists in `O(nlogn)` to do the comparison itself in `O(n)`... if not and the data set is really big, I guess you could create a fulltext index out of the `FileName`s..

Comment: extraction is tricky the format is
[0 or more chars ][client id ][0 or more chars ]
and of course ClientID is also chars
so I guess the short answer is no :-)

Comment: Is this a general problem with finding correspondences between collections?  Or is there something especially tricky with `ObservableCollections`?

Comment: @dbc general problem when collections are non sorted

Answer (score 0):

If the collections are large, you would be better off putting the list of FileName values from Collection1 into a suffix tree, and then using a lookup on that for each member of Collection2.

See https://gist.github.com/axefrog/2373868 for a sample suffix tree implementation in C#.